# how to add two array values into one array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var period = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
var marks = ['20', '15', '00', '20'];
```

i want result that is array in javascript
// returns

```
data = [{"period": "1", "marks": 20},
{"period": "2", "marks": 15},
{"period": "3", "marks": 00},
{"period": "4", "marks": 20}];
```

I want to merge these arrays which are period and marks in to array called data
thank you in advance

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results

You can use `map()` like the following way:

```js
var period = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
var marks = ['20', '15', '00', '20'];

var data = period.map((d,i) => ({period:d, marks: marks[i]}));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: what if  i want to add 3 arguments like  {"period": "4", "marks": 20,'something': 150};

Comment: In that case only thing that change will be 

period.map((d,i) => ({ period:d, marks: marks[i], somthing: something[i] }));

You can extend this object as much as possible..

Answer (score 1):

You could build an object with the names of the variables as keys and iterate all entries of the object and take the index of the arrays as index for the object of the result array.

This works for arbitrary length of the arrays an for any count of properties.

```js
var period = ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    marks = ['20', '15', '00', '20'],
    result = Object
        .entries({ period, marks })
        .reduce((r, [k, a]) => a.map((v, i) => Object.assign(r[i] || {}, { [k]: v })), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```